# Set spring properties file location from command line

Tags: java, spring, command-line, properties, startup

I have a simple Spring application with reading configuration values from a properties file. The file is configured to be on classpath by default (`@PropertySource("classpath:thefile.properties")` annotation on a configuration class). I want to be able to **optionally** use some another properties file that I can (but don't have to) specify in command line on the program startup. I.e., I eventually want to run something like this:

```
java -jar application.jar --path "some/location/thefile.properties"
```

Now values from the specified file should be used.

I have already tried using SpringBoot and the `spring.config.location` option both before and after the jar:

```
java -jar "-Dspring.config.location=file:some/location/thefile.properties" application.jar
```

- keeps using values from the file on classpath

```
java -jar application.jar "--spring.config.location=file:some/location/thefile.properties"
```

- complains about unrecognized option

My main class looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
        // Application code triggered here...
    }
}
```

I don't need to use SpringBoot, I just want to set the properties file location somehow. Any idea? And is this possible at all?

Comment: try `java -jar -Dspring.config.location=some/location/thefile.properties application.jar`, this should work fine

Comment: No, that also doesn't work. It still uses values from the file from classpath.

Comment: java -jar my-awesome-java-prog.jar --spring.config.location=file:/path-to-config-dir/

Comment: Nope, still loading the classpath file :(

Comment: if possible, remove application.properties from classpath, and then try, because works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this on your property class :

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource(value = "file:${myapp.external.config}")

 **Command**  java -jar -Dmyapp.external.config="C:\yourPath\abc.properties" xyz.jar
```

If you have multiple external properties files, example below

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource(value = {"file:${app1.config}", "file:${app2.config}"})

 **Command**  java -jar -Dapp1.config="C:\yourPath\abc1.properties" 
                        -Dapp2.config="C:\yourPath\abc2.properties" xyz.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows : `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\your.name\YourApp.jar --spring.config.location="C:/Users/your.name/yourAppProps.properties"`.